# swt - Recreate a composite

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I have a subclass of `Composite` that creates N number of combo boxes, where N is defined by an input. So when a user makes a change the number of combo boxes can potentially change. At the moment, this doesn't happen. I've tried two ways of doing this:

```
// On event, straight reconstruct, no change to number of dropdowns
myComp = new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, newNum);

// On event, dispose and reconstruct, this completely removes my composite from the gui
myComp.dispose();
myComp = new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, newNum);
```

Here is my Composite class:

```
public MyComposite(Composite parent, int num) {
    super(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    this.setText("MY Composite");
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
    this.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    combos = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        combos.put(i, new Combo(this, SWT.NONE));
    }
}
```

Is there another/better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the contents of a `Composite` you need to tell it you layout its contents again.

So after

```
myComp.dispose();
myComp = new MyComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, newNum);
```

you need to do

```
parent.layout(true, true);
```